# JAVA: Проверка входных данных, Рекурсия, Исключения

Tags: java, исключения, рекурсия, ввод

Такая проблемка возникла:

Нужно чтобы пользователь вводил число.
Если число не int (например буква), то должно выбрасываться исключение. 
А я как программист должен сделать так, чтобы программа не завершалась и не "пропускала" пользователя дальше, пока он не введёт корректное значение.

Пробовал через рекурсию. Но тк в стеке творится неведомая **** (на скрине), думаю этот способ не лучший.

Посоветуйте что сделать

При корректировке моего кода, учитывайте 1 и 2 задание лабораторной (на скрине)

[image: Непонятный разброс вывода]

[image: Задания к лабе]

Comment: Код лучше вставлять не картинкой, а текстом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одно из решений - цикл `while`.

```
        boolean check = true;
        int fN;
        while(check) {
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                check = false; //ставим false, что бы не вводить больше данные
                System.out.println(...);
                fN = sc.nextInt();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(...);
                check = true; //если вышло исключение, ставим обратно true, что бы опять вводить данные
            }
        }
```

Comment: Не подходит.
Без конца выводит строку s и ошибку из catch

Comment: @Hacker какую ошибку из catch?

Comment: System.err.println("\tОШИБКА!\n\tНеправильный ввод!");

На скрине это строка 32

Comment: @Hacker так у вас получается все время выходит ошибка в try-блоке, либо вы что-то неправильно написали.

Comment: @Hacker обновил ответ, думаю что вам станет понятнее. Если ответ помог вам, нажмите на стрелку вверх рядом с ним, а если решил вашу проблему, нажмите на галочку рядом с ним.

Comment: Я так и делал, но снова выпадал бесконечный цикл. 
И интересно то, что в блоке try, строка в S.o.u.t - выводилось на экран.
Но следующая строка fN = sc.nextInt(); - уже либо не отрабатывала, либо не знаю что. Но мне прога не давала ввести повторно своё число, в итоге получался бесконечный цикл try (до сканера) и catch

Comment: @Hacker а у вас присвоение true в try в самом верху находится?

Comment: Да, по разному пробовал. Вверху, в конце - всё равно выходит одно и то же

Comment: @Hacker нашел решение проблемы. Просто каждый раз создавать объект Scanner`а.

Answer (score 1):

Нормальный способ. Просто разделите вывод сообщения об ошибке и рекурсивный вызов функции небольшой задержкой, типа

```
Thread.sleep(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Может как-то так попробовать:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(InputFirstNumber());
}

static int InputFirstNumber() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Input first number!");
                return Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.println("\tError!");
            System.err.println("\tIncorrect data!");
            return InputFirstNumber();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким способом (скрин)
В итоге от try и catch пришлось отказаться. 
Хотя я думаю если добавить Thread.sleep(20); (как советовал тут один человек)
То мой изначальный код с рекурсией, будет работать правильно

Всем спасибо за помощь)
Поставил лайки, но тк у меня рейтинг ниже 15, они кажется не отобразятся......[image: ответ]

Comment: И насколько я понимаю, ваше решение не подходит для лабораторки, т.к. там нужно исключение.